# How to check SharePoint Cumulative Updates

Tags: administration, central-administration, cumulative-update, patching

I have two web servers installed SharePoint 2007, my intention is to check is the Cumulative Updates for SharePoint 2007 installed on both servers is the same.

I've check the SharePoint version from Site Actions --> Site Settings --> Modified All Site Settings, Version : 12.0.0.6421.

If the version were same, is that mean both SharePoint installed same Cumulative Updates?

Please help, thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 4):

That's correct!

if you ever need to confirm which update/revision of SharePoint you are running, without accessing the binary files themselves, these version numbers correspond to the version numbers reported in SharePoint Central Administration.  You can find this by going into the Operations tab, and under Topology and Services, select Servers in Farm.

**For all SharePoint 2007 updates**, you will need to install the update on each server in the farm where you have SharePoint installed (not the SQL Server unless it's also got SharePoint** installed on it, nor things like your SMTP server) and then run the Config Wizard on the server to complete its upgrade. Another note: DO NOT run the Config Wizard concurrently on more than one server at a time. The installation package updates the bits in your server and the Config Wizard then performs updates in the farm's SQL Server databases; running the Config Wizard on more than one server in a 2007 farm at the same time can cause major conflicts or corruption in your farm's databases.

Comment: The links in this answer are broken.

Comment: That's the downside of putting links. Let me clean'em up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct. Version number also indicates the CU level of the farm.

Here is one random blog [article](http://www.chrismcnulty.net/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=32) listing 2007 CU levels and corresponding version numbers.

You seem to have SP2 with no CU's installed after that.